# Segmentation fault in constructor in c++

Tags: c++, constructor, segmentation-fault

So I have the cl_Page class:

```
class cl_Page{
    public:
    cl_Page(cl_LessonMoment *parent_param);
    cl_Page(cl_SoftRoot *parent_param);
    int parent_type;
    cl_LessonMoment *parent_lmoment;
    cl_SoftRoot *parent_softroot;

    char id[256];

    //<content>
    //Backgrounds.
    str_Color bgcolor;
    cl_Image bgimage;

    //Actual content
    vector<cl_Textbox> textboxes;
    vector<cl_Button> buttons;
    vector<cl_Image> images;
    //</content>

    cl_Textbox* AddTextbox();
    cl_Button* AddButton();
    cl_Image* AddImage(char *filename = nullptr);
};
```

and the cl_Page constructors:

```
cl_Page::cl_Page(cl_LessonMoment *parent_param) : bgimage(nullptr){ //here is the segfault
    parent_lmoment = parent_param;
    parent_type = 1;
    id[0] = '\0';
    SetColor(bgcolor, 0xffffffff);
}

cl_Page::cl_Page(cl_SoftRoot *parent_param): bgimage(nullptr){ // or here if i call this constructor
    /*parent_softroot = parent_param;
    parent_type = 2;
    id[0] = '\0';
    SetColor(bgcolor, 0xffffffff);*/
}
```

What happens is that, **no matter how I call the constructors, or no matter which one I call (the second is all commented out; so basically empty), global, local or dynamically, in a function or as a member object**, I get a segmentation fault which appears to be right on the `cl_Page::cl_Page(cl_LessonMoment *parent_param) : bgimage(nullptr){` line. The call stack looks like this:

```
#0 77C460CB strcat() (C:\WINDOWS\system32\msvcrt.dll:??)
#1 0022F168 ?? () (??:??)
#2 00401905 cl_Page::cl_Page(this=0x22fbe8, parent_param=0x0) (F:\Scoala\C++\EduSoftViewer_Parser\sources\classes\soft_tree\page.cpp:10)
#3 00402B8A main() (F:\Scoala\C++\EduSoftViewer_Parser\sources\main.cpp:11)
```

On some builds before I am writing this, (with exactly the same issue) the #1 position on the call stack, where now is `?? () (??:??)` was `ntdll!RtlDosApplyFileIsolationRedirection_Ustr() (C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll:??)`.

So my question is: Does anybody know what is causing this? I really need to get this working.

If anything is unclear, just ask and I'll provide additional information.

EDIT: To clarify: I'm under Windows XP SP2 and running Code::Blocks with gcc.

EDIT 2: The cl_Image constructor:

```
cl_Image::cl_Image(char *filename_param){
    if (filename == nullptr){
        filename[0] = '\0';
    }
    else{
        strcpy(filename, filename_param);
    }
    SetPosition(position, 0, 0);
    id[0] = '\0';
    visible = 1;
    z_index = 0;
}
```

This class doesn't contain any object members, with the exception of a POD struct, `position`

EDIT 3: The cl_Image class:

```
class cl_Image{
public:
    cl_Image(char* filename_param = nullptr);


    str_Position position;
    char filename[256];
    char id[256];
    bool visible;
    int z_index;
};
```

`str_Position` is just a struct of 2 ints.

Comment: What goes on in "cl_image" constructor?

Comment: @EdwardB. care to show us what the `filename` member, `id` member, etc of `cl_Image` looks like? (for that matter, the entire class def would probably be handy)

Comment: @WhozCraig It's just a char array.

Comment: As it stands this should be closed as too localized without a doubt. You'll need to distill a more general situation you are dealing with.

Comment: @EdwardB. Its also never NULL, which is the reason you're going ker-boom. see below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty sure this is your problem:

```
cl_Image::cl_Image(char *filename_param){
    if (filename == nullptr){  // <<==== filename??? try using the param.
        filename[0] = '\0';
    }
```

Try this:

```
cl_Image::cl_Image(char *filename_param){
    if (filename_param == nullptr){
        filename[0] = '\0';
    }
```

Comment: @EdwardB. Glad to hear it. For what its worth, I'd use a `const char*` param or `const std::string&` param and a `std::string` member for this, but I'm sure you have your reasons for not doing so. If not, consider it, and an initializer list for good measure.

Answer (score 0):

I'll guess that `bgimage` can't be initialized with nullptr.

Comment: It can be initialized tis way. I just edited my question. You have the cl_Image constructor there.